# invalid syntax for discord.py

Tags: python, pip

When I was trying to install discord.py with pip it wouldn't install keep in mind I was in IDLE

```
     python3 -m pip install discord.py
File "<stdin>", line 1
python3 -m pip install discord.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know if pip is installed because when I did `pip help` it said invalid Syntax so please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: You shouldn't run this in IDLE. Run this in your terminal/shell/cmd.exe

Answer (score 1):

Pip isnt installed correctly or simply isnt installed, download the pip.py file and run it from command prompt